# Is the reaction attack from Voice of Authority still limited by the weapon's range?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, cleric

In a game with my friends, we were in combat and our Cleric used Voice of Authority to have our Fighter/Barb attack an enemy over 30ft away with a melee weapon. Thinking that the line of sight from Voice of Authority was the range of the reaction attack.

I don't think that was correct but I'm not certain and couldn't find any solid answers. So was the Cleric right or wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Nothing changes the range of the weapon attack.

Voice of Authority states:

> that ally can use their reaction immediately after the spell to make one weapon attack against a creature of your choice that you can see.
>
> If the spell targets more than one ally, you choose the ally who *can* make the attack.

This last sentence, “you choose the ally that *can* make the attack”, indicates that there can be allies eligible to be chosen for the feature who *can’t* make the attack, because the feature doesn’t change any of the rules for the attack. If you use the feature to let the fighter make an attack, all of the usual rules for that attack apply, because nothing in the feature indicates that any special rules apply. If the fighter has no eligible targets within range, they cannot make the attack.

Comment: (1/2) "you choose the ally who _can_ make the attack" _could_ be, as you say, emphasizing that the attack must be possible within the normal rules of attack. But it could also be emphasizing that once you choose the ally, the ally can then choose whether or not to attack: "that ally _can_ use their reaction" is not "that ally _must_ use their reaction..." It could also be emphasizing that when the spell targets more than one ally, among all of those who are eligible to make the attack, you choose the only one that can do so...

Comment: (2/2) I agree with you that the feature works like you say, but I am not convinced that the "can" is there to do what you say, or at least only what you say.

Answer (score 9):

### It would depend on the weapon

From the [combat rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat), under Making an Attack:

> 1. Choose a target. Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or a location.

The rule for voice of authority states:

> Voice of Authority
>
> Starting at 1st level, you can invoke the power of law to embolden an ally to attack. If you cast a spell with a spell slot of 1st level or higher and target an ally with the spell, that ally can use their reaction immediately after the spell to make one weapon attack against a creature of your choice that you can see.
>
> If the spell targets more than one ally, you choose the ally who can make the attack.

It does not specify that the attack must be made with melee weapon. So you could shoot a bow, throw a javelin etc. However, it does not override the basic rule for attacking quoted above, which is that that the target must be within range. That being said, you could technically throw a sword as an improvised weapon at an opponent but you'd still be limited by the rules on improvised weapons regarding range and damage.

Comment: Whoops didn't specify the weapon used, it was melee/5ft weapon. But that is a good point.